# How to define implicits for Map of two classes?

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework, play-json

```
case class Apple(id:String, name:String)
case class Fruit(id:String,ftype:String)

case class Basket(b:Map[Fruit,Apple])
```

How to define the play implicits as the below definition are not enough.

```
 implicit val format: Format[Fruit] = Json.format
 implicit val format: Format[Apple] = Json.format
```

This isn't working :

```
 implicit val format: Format[Basket] = Json.format
```

Answer (score 2):

The formatter are ok, but they only work for ***Case Classes***.

So all you have to do is to adjust them:

```
case class Apple(id:String, name:String)
case class Fruit(id:String,ftype:String)

case class Basket(b:Map[Fruit,Apple])
```

**Update**

Ok there is another problem. ***JSON*** has a restriction that the ***Key*** of a *Map* must be a *String*.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53896463/2750966

Ok here an example for **Play < 2.8**:

```
  implicit val formata: Format[Apple] = Json.format

  implicit val mapReads: Reads[Map[Fruit, Apple]] = (jv: JsValue) =>
    JsSuccess(jv.as[Map[String, Apple]].map { case (k, v) =>
      (k.split("::").toList match {
        case id :: ftype :: _ => Fruit(id, ftype)
        case other => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unexpected Fruit Key $other")
      }) -> v
    })

  implicit val mapWrites: Writes[Map[Fruit, Apple]] = (map: Map[Fruit, Apple]) =>
    Json.toJson(map.map { case (fruit, o) =>
      s"${fruit.id}::${fruit.ftype}" -> o
    })
  implicit val jsonMapFormat: Format[Map[Fruit, Apple]] = Format(mapReads, mapWrites)

  implicit val formatb: Format[Basket] = Json.format
```

With this example Data it works:

```
  val basket = Basket(Map(Fruit("12A", "granate") -> Apple("A11", "The Super Apple"),
     Fruit("22A", "gala") -> Apple("A21", "The Gala Premium Apple")))
  val json = Json.toJson(basket) // >> {"b":{"12A::granate":{"id":"A11","name":"The Super Apple"},"22A::gala":{"id":"A21","name":"The Gala Premium Apple"}}}
  json.as[Basket] // >> Basket(Map(Fruit(12A,granate) -> Apple(A11,The Super Apple), Fruit(22A,gala) -> Apple(A21,The Gala Premium Apple)))
```

Here the [Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/plPT1FR/0)

Comment: I am sorry, it was originally case class and it was not working.

Comment: see my update - sorry I did not spot that - maybe the exception would help in the question.

Comment: so, if we need the key as a case class/object, should we use the toString method of the case class as a key, is that a good practice @pme

Comment: You would need an identifier that is unique. In your case that would be maybe id. But this only works to write a json. To read it you would need to create a string with all the values, and parse them when reading the Json back to the Map.

Comment: Could you please give an example @pme

Comment: As of play-json 2.8 it is no longer true that the key of a Map must be a String. You only need to define a `KeyWrites` and `KeyReads` for the class.

Comment: Also, note that the macros work for normal classes as well, not just case classes. The only requirement is that the companion object has matching apply and unapply methods (which case classes automatically fulfill).

Comment: @potterpod - ok I added an example - if you have Play 2.8, see the answer of cbley

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible implementation using Play JSON 2.8:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Apple(id:String, name:String)
case class Fruit(id:String,ftype:String)

case class Basket(b:Map[Fruit,Apple])

object Apple {
  implicit val format = Json.format[Apple]
}

object Basket {
  implicit val keyReads: KeyReads[Fruit] = s => ???
  implicit val keyWrites: KeyWrites[Fruit] = f => s"${f.id}/${f.ftype}"

  implicit val format = Json.format[Basket]
}

val b = Basket(Map(Fruit("1", "sw") -> Apple("2", "boskop")))

Json.stringify(Json.toJson(b)) // -> {"b":{"1/sw":{"id":"2","name":"boskop"}}}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XbFY6amKSb6BCVCrGmgrBQ